Unit Test Errors - Clerk and Vitest
I am working on a project for work and we have a strict requirement for unit tests. I decided to go with Vitest and we're using Clerk for auth. I ran into two different issues and I'm not sure which path is easier to solve. When I run the test (one so far) using the render method from @testing-library/react I get an error that "AuthContext not found".
When I do that I get a new error that says ClerkProvider.js 2 seems to be an ES Module but shipped in a CommonJS package. You might want to create an issue to the package @clerk/nextjs" asking them to ship the file in .mjs extension or add "type": "module in their package.json.
I'm unsure how to proceed as the only issue I currently have with Clerk is that they have zero guidance on how to set up any tests within the auth context. Hoping someone has encountered this and has a pointer towards a solve.
For the AuthContext not found issue I used an approach we use in a different application. I made a wrapper for render that wraps all children in a ClerkProvider.
When I do that I get a new error that says ClerkProvider.js 2 seems to be an ES Module but shipped in a CommonJS package. You might want to create an issue to the package @clerk/nextjs" asking them to ship the file in .mjs extension or add "type": "module in their package.json.
I'm unsure how to proceed as the only issue I currently have with Clerk is that they have zero guidance on how to set up any tests within the auth context. Hoping someone has encountered this and has a pointer towards a solve.

Two things were necessary to resolve this:

require syntax resolved the module issue
I imported the AppRouterContext provider to resolve the follow on error of not being able to work outside of the app router.



const AllTheProviders: FC<{ children: ReactNode }> = ({ children }) => (
    <AppRouterContext.Provider value={{} as AppRouterInstance}>
        <React.StrictMode>
            <ClerkProvider>
                <TRPCReactProvider>
                    {children}
                </TRPCReactProvider>
            </ClerkProvider>
        </React.StrictMode>
    </AppRouterContext.Provider>
);

const customRender = (
    ui: ReactElement,
    options?: Omit<RenderOptions, "wrapper">,
) => render(ui, { wrapper: AllTheProviders, ...options });

export * from "@testing-library/react";
export { customRender as render };



